# MySQL - Group by one value and concat other values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with email and phone columns. One email can have several phones, which results in multiple rows with same email but different phone numbers.

I want to query all emails with it's phones grouped in one single column.

#### Example

Convert from this

```sql
11111  mail@mail.com
22222  mail@mail.com  
33333  mail@mail.com
44444  mail@mail.com
```

To this

```sql
mail@mail.com  11111, 22222, 33333, 44444
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you're trying to transform a numeric value to a single string. Try checking out aggregate functions that can work with strings here >> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) to the rescue:

```sql
SELECT   email, GROUP_CONCAT(other ORDER BY other ASC SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY email
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it

```sql
select email,GROUP_CONCAT(tel1,',',tel2) as phones from table group by email;
```

Thanks!